# How do I make a program in C that will read ad print specific lines from a file?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  FILE * ofile;

  char fname[100], c;

  printf("Please enter a file name: \n");
  scanf("%s", fname);

  ofile = fopen(fname, "r+");
  if (ofile == NULL)
    {
      printf("This file cannot be opened!\n");
      exit(0);
    }
  c = fgetc(ofile);
  while (c != EOF)
    {
      printf("%c", c);
      c = fgetc(ofile);
    }

  fclose(ofile);

  return 0;

}
```

This is what I have, and it just prints everything. I can't find any resources that tell me how to make it print just the first or last three lines, or how to specify lines at all. I don't need to specify by what the lines contain, just where they are.

Comment: Use a line-reading function (e.g. [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)).  Decide how you specify which lines to print (command-line arguments?).  As you read and count the input lines, decide whether the current line should be printed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually track which line you are on and compare.

```
int line = 0;
while (c != EOF)
{
    if (c == '\n')
    {
        line++;
    }
    if (line != 0)
    {
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    c = fgetc(ofile);
}
```

This addition will skip the first line, but print the rest. It can be modified as you like.